# Unity doesn't keep keystates between scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've already asked this question before, and I thought I got an answer, but it hasn't been working for me. So, here it is again.

Unity **does NOT** keep keystates between scenes. For example, let's say I'm holding down Space and tracing the word "Hello" using:

```
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        print("Hello!");
}
```

Now. Let's say that I reset the scene using:

```
Application.LoadLevel(0);
```

or

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
```

Whichever one suits you. If I reset the scene, but I'm **STILL HOLDING SPACE,** nothing happens until I lift my finger and place it down again. This is an enormous problem when I'm building my 2D Top Down game, as I was planning on having buildings and inside stuff be different scenes.  Does anyone have any ideas? Please don't suggest

```
DontDestroyOnLoad
```

Because that doesn't work. I've tried it, and you may try it yourself. Any other ideas or tricks or something I'm missing? I'm desperate here. Thanks.

I'm using C# and Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unity does NOT keep keystates between scenes

That is partially not true. What happens is that Unity's `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)` will return `false` in the **first frame** when new scene is loaded. This happens in the first frame only. After that, it will continue return `true` if space bar is still down. This statement is based on Unity **5.4.0b13**. You have to update to that if you are seeing different result.

Solution is to put your `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)` in a `coroutine` then wait one frame with `yield return null;` before checking for a key press.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(readKey());
}

bool keepReading = false;
IEnumerator readKey()
{
    if (keepReading)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    keepReading = true;

    yield return null;

    while (keepReading)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not down!");
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}

void stopReading()
{
    keepReading = false;
}
```

Another option is to use a boolean variable to determine when in next frame.

```
bool afterFirstFrame = false;
void Update()
{
    if (afterFirstFrame)
    {
        //Put your code here

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hello!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not down!");
        }
    }

    if (!afterFirstFrame)
    {
        afterFirstFrame = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm on 5.3. I guess that may be a reason. Thanks, give me a while to check it out before I mark you.

Comment: @GMR516 Try the code I have before updating. If you still have problems then update Unity to my version. I tested it to verify.

Comment: I tested both codes on the latest version, (5.4) and it still did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is now, perhaps it's my keyboard or something weird. If it's working for you, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: @GMR516 Both of my answers worked for me. Did you modify the code in my answer? If so, update the current code you have in your answer and I will look at it. If you want to see my test code that shows it works I can link it here so that you can test it yourself. If you are satisfied with the ejsd1989's answer you can accept it.

Comment: Mind uploading your project file somewhere so I can download it and test that, just to make sure that it's not something else in my project please?

Comment: @GMR516 ok I will.

Comment: @GMR516 There  are are 2 scenes. Each one with different script from my answer and a code that loads the scene every 3 seconds. Run the project then hold down the space bar. The cube should still continue rotating even after loading new scene. http://wikisend.com/download/389326/GMR516.rar If that doesn't work then explain what doesn't work. Also provide what Os version you are using. If it works, then there something wrong with your code that you must post for further help.

Comment: That's... extremely odd. It works. And I slapped the rotate code into an Update() function and even when the scene loaded it kept it. I'm going to experiment with a new project and see if I can find what the problem was with my old code.

Comment: @GMR516 Nice. Go ahead. I now believe there is something wrong with your code or project.

Comment: What the HECK?! I tested my code, didn't work. Made a new project, moved the player into it, tested, it worked. So I went back to my old project and tested again. And it WORKED?! I have absolutely no idea what was wrong now, but thank you guys for being so helpful. :)

Comment: @GMR516 I don't know lol but let me know if it stops working.Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I figured out what it is: I was using the "R" button to reset the scene. If you're holding two buttons and the scene changes, only one key's state carries over. I have faith that this will reproduce correctly for you, if you'd like to test it. Any ideas on how to carry over more than one key? (I also doubt it's a ghosting issue, as I'm testing the space bar and the right key to prevent that. Also tested a few other keys, same deal.)  Would my best bet just be to keep it all in one scene or something? My worry is that'll be cluttered though.

Comment: @GMR516 I was able to reproduce that. Looks like a bug to me. What keys do you want to detect after new scene?

Comment: Well, I'm using the arrow keys for the top down movement. If the player has like, the right and up button held down, it should move them diagonally. I'm trying to think of a work-around for this, but I can't really think of anything. So I'd like to detect right and up, left and down, down and right, and left and up.

Comment: @GMR516 Will see if there is an easy way to do this. Will let you know

Comment: @Programmer I'm hitting the very same issue in Unity 2018.3. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I decided to make all the "levels" in one scene and just move the player's position after a fade out because of this issue. Then it works, of course, because you never change scenes. I would recommend re-thinking your approach, as it doesn't look like Unity will ever fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The following may not be the cleanest method, but it worked for some rough testing.

By using a PlayerPrefs, you can store a representation of the state and test it in your Start() function of the newly loaded scene.

The functionality it will create is such that it will validate the first frame to be true if the user held it prior to switching scenes. It will stop validating true only if the user allows the button to be released.

Once again, this is an implementation that sort of forces the manipulation, but will need to be customized to ensure that it behaves appropriately in other situations.

```
private bool isPressed = false;

void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Pressed") != 0)
        isPressed = true;
    else
        isPressed = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isPressed)
        print("Hello World");

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (!isPressed) isPressed = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        isPressed = false;
    }
}

public void SaveButtonState()
{
    if(isPressed)
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Pressed", 1);
    else
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Pressed", 0);
}
```

Comment: It works, but it's a little hacky. Apparently, unity 5.4 down there added the functionality of holding the button between scenes, so I'm gonna go check that out. If it still doesn't work, I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: @GMR516 Indeed it's a bit hacky haha. Either way, hope you get it working in the best fashion for your application!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading your interior level additivly somewhere below your main level.  Than just move player to this point after player would leave building you unload a scene and move player back where he was.